# Nothing Happening a Simple Condition in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In excel, I want to impose a cell to be 0 if a condition is matched, but editable if not. My condition is that another cell's value = 1. This is my minimal example VBA line:

```
If Range("B4").Value = 1 Then Range("C4").Value = 0
```

But nothing is happening even though B4 is set to 1! Is there something missing in this code? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean cell `B4` or cell `R4` ... likely a typo at the end of your question perhaps?

Comment: Where is this code found? Is it in an event?  In a module? in the worksheet code?  Your verbiage says `R4` and your code says `B4` which is it?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the offending line, when hit, type  ?Range("B4").Value in the immediate window. What is the value?

Comment: So sorry for the inconvenience, I meant B4 also in the text - I wrote this simple code because I want a cell to be editable, unless a condition is met (B4=1), in which case the cell should be set equal to 0

Comment: what is the exact value of cell B4 ?

Comment: Exact value of cell B4 is 1. I've found an alternative to my original issue, which was to make the cell editable unless a condition was met: I made another cell editable and called that value only if the condition is not met, otherwise I set the cell to 0. Not so nice since it requires an extra cell but it's an ok fix for the purpose! Thank you all for the attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualify the `Range` objects with the specific worksheets you want to analyze / alter. This is best practice for VBA and ensures the code acts on the specific places you need it to.

For example:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    If .Range("B4").Value = 1 Then .Range("C4").Value = 0

End With
```

Or

```
If Worksheets("mySheet").Range("B4").Value = 1 Then

    Worksheets("yourSheet").Range("C4").Value = 0

End If
```

Comment: Thank you - that's an important point. However, still nothing is happening. In my case, "mySheet"="yourSheet". Other than that, I am using the exact same (second) code you suggest. So strange.

Answer (score 0):

You have to refer to the sheet as well. E.g.,

```
If ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Value = 1 Then ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Value = 0
```

To see the sheet, which you were referring to, try this:

```
Sub TestMe()
    If Range("B4").Value = 1 Then Range("C4").Value = 0
    MsgBox (Range("B4").Parent.Name)
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet` may also return the wrong answer as well!

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - depends what the OP is doing. But the way he says it, I think that he is watching the sheet in front of him and it is not being updated.

Comment: True, I was working with the active sheet. Just in case I selected the sheet by name. Still nothing is happening